# Is it possible for several ASP.NET websites on the same VM to share DLLS & maybe aspx files?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Have been wondering this for some time!, If several websites used very similar code DLLS, it would be nice for them to share the files, I'm not worried about a performance hit,

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly.

There are two basic ways to do it.

1. Create your dlls and have them referenced by your site and have them copied local to the deployed website.
2. Give you dlls strong names and have the referenced in the gac.  All websites then can use the gaced dlls with out the need to be copied locally.

Comment: Thanks! :) Also, is it possible to share .aspx files? I.E, each website refers to a few .aspx files at a higher directory level than the website? 
E.G /wwwroot/website1 , /wwwroot/website2 , /wwwroot/_SharedFiles

Comment: I also wonder if the GAC method would make the websites slower as they'd all my reading from the same DLL?

Comment: @Baconbeatnz: You can share aspx files but the general way to do that is through the use of master pages.  Gac is not a slower implementation but it can be a headche to manage.